# How do I make Notepad++ my default editor in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, notepad++

In POSH-GIT, a Git add-on for PowerShell, when I issue a 'commit' command, Notepad++ opens for the commit comment, and unlike normal Notepad++ operation, it prompts to save when I exit with `Alt-X`.

How do I set this up for whenever I use PowerShell?

By 'default editor', I mean I want to type `edit <filename>`, and have Powershell open that file in Notepad++, but with a prompt to save when I close Notepad++, which is not the normal behaviour. Not on mine at least; Notepad++ just caches open files in memory/on disk when it closes.

Comment: PowerShell does not have a default editor. Please clarify what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Is your question how to associate Notepad++ as the default editor, or how to associate certain commands with auto-execution of that identical sequence (or other sequences?)?

Comment: @fixer1234 That is my intention, thank you for your patience with my lack of clarity.

Comment: Edit is not an alias by default in Powershell. If you have one you can use Get-Alias to see it's definition and should be able to change it with Set-Alias. 

As for the prompt when you close Notepadd++, from what I read versions 6.6 and later should automatically save those files periodically. You can change the settings in Settings->Preferences->Backup->Enable session snapshot and periodic backup.

Comment: When I close with alt+f4 I don't get the prompt, when I use alt+X I do.

Comment: Not for Notepadd++, but for vscode users: 
`$env:EDITOR = 'code-insiders --wait'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really the solution to my question, but it is the closest I have come. It is a PowerShell script that totally replaces Notepad with Notepad++ system wide.

[Replace Notepad.exe with Notepad++ Using PowerShell in Windows 10](http://www.bobhodges.net/home/replace-notepad-with-notepad-using-powershell)

The linked script only replaces file `notepad.exe` with the executable of Notepad++ after it moved original file to `notepad.exe.bak`. And if the Notepad++ is 7.5.9 or above, then it adds a value into key `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe`.

Comment: On an old Win2k I was used to see  `notepad++.exe` materially renamed in `notepad.exe`... and `notepad.exe` in `ms.notepad.exe`... `:-)`